# Download not working once the size less than buffer length c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sharepoint

today while doing a logic for downloading large size files, i am facing an error. For downloading what my logic is am spltting the file into 10KB chunks and then integrating it and is downloading.While downloading what happening is like each time am reducing the total size by 10KB , but once the remaining length is less than 10KB my download is getting interuppted. Please find the below code of mine and let me know if any change needed in my logic.

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            System.IO.Stream iStream = null;
            // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
            // Length of the file:
            int length;
            // Total bytes to read:
            long dataToRead;
            // Identify the file to download including its path.
            string filepath = "C:\\Users\\GZT00000000000001020\\Desktop\\123.zip";
            // Identify the file name.
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            try
            {
                iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
                dataToRead = iStream.Length;
                Page.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                // Read the bytes.
                while (dataToRead > 0)
                {
                    // Verify that the client is connected.
                    if (Page.Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        if( (dataToRead < 10000) && (dataToRead!=-1))
                        {
                            length = (int)dataToRead;
                            buffer = new Byte[length];
                            dataToRead = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Read the data in buffer.
                            length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                        }
                        // Write the data to the current output stream.
                        Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                        Page.Response.Flush();
                        if (dataToRead > 10000)
                        {
                            buffer = new Byte[10000];
                            dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                        }
                        else if(dataToRead!=-1)
                        {
                            length =(int)dataToRead ;
                            buffer = new Byte[length];
                        }                         
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                        dataToRead = -1;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Trap the error, if any.
                Page.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (iStream != null)
                {
                    //Close the file.
                    iStream.Close();
                }
                Page.Response.Close();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `iStream.Read` in the branch where `dataToRead` < 10000